# Losing member data when creating a thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I find it hard to explain the problem, so I'll post the code and explain what happens, and then ask how to make it do what I want.  Firstly, I create a thread within a child process:

```
pid_t childpid = fork();

if(childpid == -1){
  cout << "Failed to fork." << endl;   
}
else if(childpid == 0){     
  //request threads
  pthread_t p1, p2, p3;          

  struct arg_struct args1, args2, args3;

  args1.name = "data Joe Smith";
  args1.num_req = n;
  args1.buff_size = b;
  pthread_create(&p1, NULL, &mythreadfunc, (void *)&args1);   
}
```

This is the `struct arg_struct`:

```
struct arg_struct{
    string name;
    int num_req;
    int curr_value;
    int buff_size;
};
```

And the `mythreadfunc:`

```
void *mythreadfunc(void *arguments){ 
    struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *)arguments;
    string local_name = args->name;     
    int local_num_req = args->num_req;
    //request new thread
    RequestChannel chan("control", RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
    cout << "done." << endl;
    string reply1 = chan.send_request("newthread");

    cout << "Reply to request 'newthread' is " << reply1 << "'" << endl;

    RequestChannel chan2(reply1, RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE); 

    cout<<"local_name:  "<<local_name<<endl;    //returns incorrect value***
    cout<<"local_num_req:  "<<local_num_req<<endl;  //returns incorrect value***

    //close up all channels
    string reply2 = chan2.send_request("quit");
    cout << "Reply to request 'quit' is '" << reply2 << "'" << endl;
    string reply3 = chan.send_request("quit");
    cout << "Reply to request 'quit is '"<< reply3 << "'" << endl;
}
```

In the two lines that utilize `local_name` and `local_num_req`, there are problems.  I compile fine, but the two variables always seem to store something different each time.  Sometimes it works properly, while sometimes they hold garbage values and the program never executes them (or anything following).  I tried to use the original names (i.e. `args->name`) without the local variables, but the problem is the same.  My best guess is that my `args_struct` handles the variables wrong, but I don't know why it would only fail part of the time.

How can I have the correct variable values in the `mythreadfunc`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create the argument for your new thread on the heap, it's going out of scope in the calling function and so isn't valid for use by your thread(s):

```
struct arg_struct *arg1 = new arg_struct;

args1->num_req = n;
// etc...

pthread_create(&p1, NULL, &mythreadfunc, (void *) args1);
```

Comment: In C++, it's an error to use malloc on a struct that contains a std::string (i.e. on a non-POD struct), new should be used instead `arg_struct *arg1 = new arg_struct;` Mind you Nibirue does seem a bit confused about whether his code is C or C++.

Comment: @jahhaj thanks, missed that he was using `string` there but should've been obvious from his assignment to it in the arg. updated the answer

Comment: @jahhaj, no, it's not an error, `malloc` just creates a block of memory, that's fine.  It's an error to start using the object without constructing it (i.e. initializing the memory) which could be done by using placement new.

Comment: @Jonathon Wakely, you're right of course, but for the sake of brevity I ignored that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

`p1` and `args1` both go out of scope as soon as the new thread is created, so they no longer exist while `mythreadfunc` is running.

To fix the code you need to make the lifetime of those objects longer than the lifetime of the new thread that uses them.  That can be done by creating the objects on the heap, or by creating them in an enclosing scope that ensures they do not go out of scope until the new thread has finished:

```
pthread_t p1, p2, p3;
struct arg_struct args1, args2, args3;

pid_t childpid = fork();

if(childpid == -1){
  cout << "Failed to fork." << endl;   
}
else if(childpid == 0){     
  //request threads

  args1.name = "data Joe Smith";
  args1.num_req = n;
  args1.buff_size = b;
  pthread_create(&p1, NULL, &mythreadfunc, (void *)&args1);   
}

// ...

void* res = pthread_join(&p1);

// safe for `args1` to go out of scope now
```